# Did iOS 8 break NSURLCache?

Tags: caching, ios8, afnetworking, xcode6

Long story short, I just updated to Xcode 6 to check how my app works on iOS 8. I noticed that it doesn't use the cache even though it should. I'm using AFNetworking setting the cachePolicy like this:

```
sessionManager.requestSerializer.cachePolicy = NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad;
```

I still have an iOS 7 device in which I tested the same code and it works there as expected.

Does anyone have a solution for this, or do we need to wait for Apple to fix it?

Comment: I've noticed something very similar with NSURLSession. I think NSURLConnection is still working correctly with NSURLCache.

Comment: I've just noticed the same (with AFNetworking2) with my custom NSURLCache subclass (storeCachedResponse:forRequest: is getting called, but cachedResponseForRequest: is never getting called).

Answer (score 12):

I'm almost certain that iOS 8.0 has broken `NSURLSession`'s ability to cache HTTP response data. I've opened a radar with Apple about this issue.

Here's some sample code I wrote to prove this:

```
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
NSURLCache *URLCache = [[NSURLCache alloc] initWithMemoryCapacity:4 * 1024 * 1024
                                                     diskCapacity:32 * 1024 * 1024
                                                         diskPath:nil];
[NSURLCache setSharedURLCache:URLCache];

dispatch_semaphore_t semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);
NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://i.imgur.com/b5pyONe.jpg"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL
                                         cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad
                                     timeoutInterval:5];
NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Error occurred");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Fetched resource!");
    }
    dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore);
}];
[task resume];

dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);

request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL
                           cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataDontLoad
                       timeoutInterval:5];
task = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Something bad happened: %@", error);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Fetched resource!");
    }
}];
[task resume];
```

Even creating your own `NSURLSession` -- with an `NSURLSessionConfiguration` that has an `NSURLCache` that you create yourself -- won't fix this issue. For now, if you need cached responses badly, you have to use `NSURLConnection`.

Comment: That's what I thought. I'm amazed how many problems Apple has had lately.

Comment: Richard, do you have any answers from apple about NSURLCache? I really need cache in my application but it is broken in iOS 8...

Comment: @JohnKakon Haven't heard anything from Apple yet. Just tested with Xcode 6.1 GM and it's still broken.

If you need caching, you must use NSURLConnection.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I use AFNetworking 2, so I can't change the method easily...

Comment: @JohnKakon You can use `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager`, which is the AFNetworking class that uses NSURLConnection to power its network calls.

Comment: Does anyone know if Apple fixed this yet?

Comment: @SamYoungNY This is still broken in 8.3.

Comment: Fixed in iOS 9.2 probably earlier also. In 8.4 broken.

Answer (score 5):

NSURLConnection is not working properly. It will store responses properly, but it [never purges the cache](http://blog.airsource.co.uk/2014/10/11/nsurlcache-ios8-broken/) (diskCapacity is ignored) on iOS 8.0 so the cache will [grow without limit](http://blog.airsource.co.uk/2014/10/13/nsurlcache-ios8-broken-2/), though manually clearing the cache does work. This is [fixed in iOS 8.1](http://blog.airsource.co.uk/2014/10/21/nsurlcache-ios8-broken-3/), although removeCachedResponseForRequest: still does not work.

Also, if you specify a cache size smaller than 5 megs, it will not cache anything.

Answer (score 1):

Both `NSURLCache` and `NSURLSession` are buggy.
Even if you set `NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad` for request, iOS may try to reload file from server.
It happens for example when cached response has `Vary` header.
Also please notice that method

```
- (NSCachedURLResponse *)cachedResponseForRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
```

use `User-Agent` header from request to distinguish cached objects.
It means iOS will store the same file twice, if you access it by NSURLSession and UIWebView, because `User-Agent` is different.